# on submit compare two dynamically generated column in a table and display alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with few column, all are disable except two fields.  
Compare the value in the first Quanity column with the value in the second Quanity column.  
If value in the second Quanity column is more that first Quanity column it should display alert.  
When I tried comparison based on **ID's** it works fine with one row but when there are multiply row it does not work.  
When I tried comparison based on **classes** it work on the first row but it not comparing 2nd row.  
Thanks in Advance.  
**NOTE**: All the Row are generated dynamically from the back end.

```js
/*avaliable products valadations*/
function validateAvaliable(){
  var aproducts = parseInt($( ".available-quanity" ).val());
  var sproducts = parseInt($( ".send-quanity" ).val());
  console.log(aproducts);
  console.log(sproducts );
  if (aproducts < sproducts) {
    alert("send products are more");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
            <form onsubmit="return validateAvaliable()" class="available-products-table" id="available-products-table"  name="available-products">
        <table class="table">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Avaliable Products</legend>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>S.no</th>
                      <th>Product Name</th>
                      <th>Product ID</th>
                      <th>Quanity</th>
                      <th>Brand</th>
                      <th>Color</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Quanity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-sno" disabled value="1" class="form-control available-sno"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-name" disabled value="shoes" class="form-control available-name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-id" disabled value="123" class="form-control available-id"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="available-quanity" disabled value="50" class="form-control available-quanity"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-brand" disabled value="adidas" class="form-control available-brand"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-color" disabled value="black" class="form-control available-color"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" class="form-control product-status"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-quanity" required class="form-control send-quanity"></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-sno" disabled value="2" class="form-control available-sno"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-name" disabled value="shoes" class="form-control available-name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-id" disabled value="456" class="form-control available-id"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="available-quanity" disabled value="30" class="form-control available-quanity"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-brand" disabled value="adidas" class="form-control available-brand"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-color" disabled value="red" class="form-control available-color"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" class="form-control product-status"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-quanity" required class="form-control send-quanity"></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Enter Franchise ID</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-franchise-is" id="product-status" required></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></td>
                    
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </fieldset>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$( ".available-quanity" )` and `$( ".send-quanity" )` both return lists of elements, so you will have to use a loop to compare all values, Also use `event.preventDefault()` so that the form doesn't submit. something like this:

```js
/*avaliable products valadations*/
function validateAvaliable(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var aproducts = $( ".available-quanity" );
  var sproducts = $( ".send-quanity" );
  //console.log(aproducts);
  //console.log(sproducts);
  for(var i=0;i<aproducts.length;i++){
  if (parseInt($(aproducts[i]).val()) < parseInt($(sproducts[i]).val())) {
    alert("send products are more");
    return false;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
            <form onsubmit="return validateAvaliable(event)" class="available-products-table" id="available-products-table"  name="available-products">
        <table class="table">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Avaliable Products</legend>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>S.no</th>
                      <th>Product Name</th>
                      <th>Product ID</th>
                      <th>Quanity</th>
                      <th>Brand</th>
                      <th>Color</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Quanity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-sno" disabled value="1" class="form-control available-sno"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-name" disabled value="shoes" class="form-control available-name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-id" disabled value="123" class="form-control available-id"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="available-quanity" disabled value="50" class="form-control available-quanity"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-brand" disabled value="adidas" class="form-control available-brand"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-color" disabled value="black" class="form-control available-color"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" class="form-control product-status"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-quanity" required class="form-control send-quanity"></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-sno" disabled value="2" class="form-control available-sno"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-name" disabled value="shoes" class="form-control available-name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-id" disabled value="456" class="form-control available-id"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="available-quanity" disabled value="30" class="form-control available-quanity"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-brand" disabled value="adidas" class="form-control available-brand"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-color" disabled value="red" class="form-control available-color"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" class="form-control product-status"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-quanity" required class="form-control send-quanity"></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Enter Franchise ID</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-franchise-is" id="product-status" required></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></td>
                    
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </fieldset>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$( ".available-quanity" )` and `$( ".send-quanity" )` gives you array of elements (one for each row). So you should iterate over these arrays with some loop:

```
var aproducts = $( ".available-quanity" );
var sproducts = $( ".send-quanity" );
for (var i = 0; i < aproducts.length; i++){
     // Values per row:
     var aproducts_val = parseInt($(aproducts[i]).val()); // Or just parseInt(aproducts[i].value)
     var sproducts_val = parseInt($(sproducts[i]).val());
     // ... Compare here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple rows should be in loop to check the values. Please refer below code snippet..

```
function validateAvaliable(){

  $("table tr").each(function(tr) {

  if($(this).find('.available-quanity').length && $(this).find('.send-quanity').length) {
  var aproducts = parseInt($(this).find('.available-quanity').val());
  var sproducts = parseInt($(this).find('.send-quanity').val());

  console.log('test',aproducts);
  console.log('test1',sproducts );
  if (aproducts < sproducts) {
    alert("send products are more");
    return false;
  }
  }
  } );
}
```

```js
/*avaliable products valadations*/
$('#submit').on('click',function(event){

    $("table tr").each(function(tr) {

      if($(this).find('.available-quanity').length && $(this).find('.send-quanity').length) {
          var aproducts = parseInt($(this).find('.available-quanity').val());
          var sproducts = parseInt($(this).find('.send-quanity').val());

          console.log('test',aproducts);
          console.log('test1',sproducts );
          if (aproducts < sproducts) {
            alert("send products are more");
            event.preventDefault();
          }
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
            <form class="available-products-table" id="available-products-table" method="POST"  name="available-products">
        <table class="table">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Avaliable Products</legend>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>S.no</th>
                      <th>Product Name</th>
                      <th>Product ID</th>
                      <th>Quanity</th>
                      <th>Brand</th>
                      <th>Color</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Quanity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-sno" disabled value="1" class="form-control available-sno"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-name" disabled value="shoes" class="form-control available-name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-id" disabled value="123" class="form-control available-id"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="available-quanity" disabled value="50" class="form-control available-quanity"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-brand" disabled value="adidas" class="form-control available-brand"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-color" disabled value="black" class="form-control available-color"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" class="form-control product-status"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-quanity" required class="form-control send-quanity"></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-sno" disabled value="2" class="form-control available-sno"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-name" disabled value="shoes" class="form-control available-name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-id" disabled value="456" class="form-control available-id"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="available-quanity" disabled value="30" class="form-control available-quanity"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-brand" disabled value="adidas" class="form-control available-brand"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-color" disabled value="red" class="form-control available-color"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" class="form-control product-status"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-quanity" required class="form-control send-quanity" ></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Enter Franchise ID</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-franchise-is" id="product-status" required></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></td>
                    
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </fieldset>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have another small problem in your code. the form should not submit if alert is shown, in your code it is submitting. I already add return and return false keyword in HTML and JS files.

Comment: updated. please use event.preventDefault to remove default action. also this code will check from tr tag so it will get the proper input to match ..

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle.
I have added class mytr for tr.
http://jsfiddle.net/pzphbnxb/42/

```
$(document).on('change', '.send-quanity', function(e){
   var elem = $(this);
   var changeVal = $(this).val();
   var myval = elem.closest('.mytr').find('.available-quanity').val();
   if(parseInt(changeVal) > parseInt(myval)){
    alert('value greater');
   }
});
```